# Samsung Galaxy R - No files in default music player

Tags: music-player

I own a Samsung Galaxy R. Recently, I could not find any files in default music player after I installed PowerAMP. How do I bring back the files in the default music player? I've checked by uninstalling PowerAMP... that didn't help!

Comment: Just to make sure, there were files visible in the default music player before you installed PowerAMP?

Comment: Yes it was visible "THelper"

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes have problems with the media indexer ("Media Storage" Service), then I just do the following to let it rescan and rebuild all media files on the phone:

- Settings > Apps > All Apps > "Default music player" > Force stop, Clear data, Clear cache
- Settings > Apps > ALl Apps > "Media Storage" > Force stop, Clear data, Clear cache
- Reboot phone
- Unlock your phone and wait 10-20 minutes, don't do anything, don't open your Music App, don't care if it locks again just let it be for at least 10-20 min.

Comment: Not working dude...